# array of random numbers

Tags: javascript, random

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Random number generator without dupes in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796786/random-number-generator-without-dupes-in-javascript)
>   [Generate 8 unique random numbers between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-8-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

HI,
  I want to create an array of random numbers which should have unique values.i want to do this using java script ,Can any one give me a solution...?

Comment: Random numbers might result in repeats... just sayin'

Comment: If the numbers themselves need not be random consider a simple [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). However, the question this is "getting closed" for follows this line of thinking -- which is *different* than getting a list of unique random numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array of numbers:

```
var min = 0,
    max = 1000,
    i,
    arr = [];

for (i = min; i<max; i++)
{
    arr.push(i);
}
```

Then [shuffle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling).