# Random array selection without selecting twice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

So, I am attempting to select a random entry from an array, and then make it so that particular entry will not be selected again until every entry has been selected.
Basically, I don't want to see any of the same entries, until all of the entries in the array have been selected.

So if this were my array…

```
keywords =
[
 "ppc",
 "games",
 "advertise",
 "meta",
 "home",
 "gaming",
 "welcome"
]
var keyword = keywords[Math.floor(Math.random()*keywords.length)]
document.write(keyword);
```

I would not want to see an output of:

```
meta, advertise, home, meta, gaming, welcome, ppc, welcome
```

since meta was selected a second time before everything had been selected once.
I would like to see something more like:

```
meta, advertise, gaming,ppc, welcome, home, games, advertise, ppc,
```

since this did not select any entry multiple times before every entry had been randomly selected.( the second loop started at the second "advertise" in case you didn't catch the differences.

But as you can see from the code that I have posted above, I do not know how to do this. I have seen examples where the entries that were randomly selected, were actually deleted from the array entirely but this is not what I want to do. I just want every entry to be selected once, and then for the process to be restarted.

Does anyone know the code for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [array of random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373306/array-of-random-numbers)

Answer (score 8):

You could use the *Array.sort()* function to sort it randomly.

```
// random sort function
function shuffle(a, b)
{
   return Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
}

var keywords = ["ppc", "games", "advertise", "meta", "home", "gaming", "welcome"];

var randomKeywords = keywords.sort(shuffle); // new instance of a sorted randomly copy of the array

alert(randomKeywords);
```

**update:**

A better solution for shuffling is using Fisher-Yates Shuffle, as found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/508029).

```js
function shuffle(array)
{
  var m = array.length, t, i;
  while (m > 0) 
  {
 i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
 t = array[m];
 array[m] = array[i];
 array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}

var keywords = ["ppc", "games", "advertise", "meta", "home", "gaming", "welcome"];

shuffle(keywords); // shuffles the array

alert(keywords);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me with Firefox and Opera on Linux. I need to take away the `-1` in `shuffle()`. If how sort handles `0` from the sorting function is implementation dependent then how about `return (Math.random() > 0.5) ? -1 : 1;` in the body of `shuffle()`?

Answer (score 5):

A very simplistic way to do this would be to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) every times you select a random element and once the array is empty re-fill it with the original values.

Example :

```
(function () {
    var arr = [];

    window.getRandomThing = function () {
        if (arr.length === 0) {
            refill();
        }

        return arr.splice(Math.random() * arr.length, 1)[0];
    };

    function refill () {
        arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    }
} ());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy of the original Array, then use `.splice()` to grab a value at a random index, and *remove* it from the copy Array.

Because the copy is being reduced by one each time, you can simply do it `while( copy.length )`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fMXTF/

```
var keywords = [
 "ppc",
 "games",
 "advertise",
 "meta",
 "home",
 "gaming",
 "welcome"
];

var copy = keywords.slice();

while( copy.length ) {

    var keyword = copy.splice( Math.floor(Math.random()*copy.length), 1 );
    document.write(keyword + '<br>');

}
```

Notice that the random number is based off `copy.length`, which, because of the `.splice()`, is reduced by 1 in each iteration. Therefore it ensures the random number is always based on the *current* `length` of the copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the array changing you could randomize the order of the elements in the array and then print the array from first element to last.

OR

You could make another array of values 1 to N (where n is the number of elements).  Randomize the order of that array and then use that as an index to the array as you iterate over it from the first to last.

Answer (score 0):

Store the numbers (indices) you've seen in a hash, then when you try look at a new word you can check the hash, if you've already seen it, generate a new number. Make sure to check to see if the hash length is the same as the array length though.

This avoids altering the array.

Comment: But suppose you have an array of 1000 indices, the probability of finding a unique indice would grow exponentially with each iteration. For the last selection you would have a 1 in 1000 chance of ending the function. So the loop would be iterating an extra 1000 times, maybe even more. This also becomes more of a problem when you add indices. Your picking function could take minutes to end.

Comment: The best solution is to pick a random indice, then swap that indice to the end of the array with the one you picked, then loop again using (array.Length - 1 - i) You're guaranteed an optimal selection of O/n.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [user113716](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7133416/1250044), but optimized it a bit.

```
var arr = [
    "ppc",
    "games",
    "advertise",
    "meta",
    "home",
    "gaming",
    "welcome"];

Array.prototype.shuffle = Array.prototype.shuffle || function () {
    var copy = this.slice(), arr = [];
    while (copy.length) arr.push(copy.splice((Math.random() * copy.length) << 0));
    return arr;
};

alert(arr.shuffle());
```