# Javascript : Exclude an element from a random set - (curiosity)

Tags: javascript, random

I have a question regarding javascript `Math.random()`:

I have (for a game I'm building) to randomly generate every number from a given set (i.e. from 0 to 1000) and every time I have to generate a number, I have to check if that number has already been "generated".

The solution is pretty easy thinking about a simple algorithm that checks if the random integer is already present in the generated set. It loops generating numbers until it can't find it.
A snippet below:

```
/* ... */
for(var i = 0; i<upperBound; i++){
    var randN = Math.floor(Math.random()*upperBound);
    while(myRandomNumbers.contains(randN)){
        loops++;
        randN = Math.floor(Math.random()*upperBound);
    }
    myRandomNumbers.push(randN);
}
/* ... */
```

[running example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/ZTLt9/)

I'd like to know: is this the best way to achieve this? or are there any ways, instead of looping until it generates a "good" number, to exclude a particular set in the random generation?

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796786/random-number-generator-without-dupes-in-javascript) will help. Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-8-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100).

Comment: @patrick dw: it's my same solution, recursive ;)

Comment: Yes, I read too quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Generate the set of numbers in order.
2. Sort the list randomly.

Here's an example using a [naive, biased sort](http://phrogz.net/JS/JavaScript_Random_Array_Sort.html):

```
for (var nums=[],i=0;i<1000;++i) nums[i]=i+1;
nums.sort(function(){ return Math.random()-0.5 });
```

Then you can just `pop()` numbers off of `nums` to get the next 'random' number, guaranteed to never have been used before.

Comment: As noted in the answer, this won't give a very random distribution, and will have different bias in different browsers. The Fisher-Yates shuffle isn't that much more code and will do much better.

Comment: See the `shuffle()` function in the file I linked to for an implementation of Fisher-Yates.

Answer (score 1):

If your range of number is not prohibitively large, you could simply generate a list with all the numbers, randomise it, then pick it off one by one.

Here's a quick hack of your sample implementation to show this method in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ZTLt9/8/

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an array and randomly shuffle it:

```
function shuffle(arr) {
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, temp, index;
    while (i--) {
        index = Math.floor(i * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
    return shuffled;
}

// Create the array
var i = 1000, arr = [];
while (i--) arr[i] = i;

// Shuffle it
arr = shuffle(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about an array of booleans 1001 big.

When you want to check of the number has been generated, all you need to do is check the number at that position in the array:

```
if (!arr[randomnumber]){
    arr[randomnumber] = true;
}
```

At the end, you can scan the array to find the numbers you need.

This has the added side effect of sorting your numbers, as the scan will pick them out in order.

Something similar to this was the subject of one of my blog posts: 
http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2010/05/27/generate-and-sort-lottery-numbers/

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to generate an array of numbers, then shuffle it using the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle).

Here is the JavaScript example given in the Wikipedia article:

```
var n = a.length;
for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

(This assumes you have an array 'a' that contains the items you wish to shuffle.)